# Cant put sound button into fragment

Tags: android

So I have two apps created. One is making sound when I click the button and the second one has a navigation drawer activity. All I want to do is put this button with sound to the one of the fragments I have created but it doesnt work for me. Im total beginner who just watching tutorials on youtube

I want to put this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SoundPool mySound;
int anotheroneId;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    anotheroneId = mySound.load(this, R.raw.anotherone, 1);
```

Into this

```
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three,container,false);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the method onActivityCreated like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mySound = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    anotheroneId = mySound.load(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.anotherone, 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks it solved most of the problems but there is still one problem
http://imgur.com/a/6z4qU

Comment: That's easiest: getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: and where exactly should i put it ? i put it in public void and nothing happened

Comment: I've edited my first answer. Look at the code again, please

Comment: it worked! but when i click on button, app stop working